# Compiling icmp related codes under cygwin (missing "icmp" struct)

Tags: c, cygwin, icmp

I'm using cygwin to compile a network tool(*iffinder*).

After `./configure` and `make` i have a problem that i guess is related to `struct icmp`. Where is the `icmp` struct in header files. I searched for it in cygwin header files, but i didn't find anything.

**How can i compile source codes which need `icmp`, in cygwin?**

If it helps, you can find the source code of *iffinder* [here](http://www.caida.org/tools/measurement/iffinder/)

*Note: I have `ip_icmp.h`  in my cygwin's header files.*

---

Compile error:

> iffinder.c:1059: warning: "struct icmp" declared inside parameter list
>
> iffinder.c:1059: warning: its scope is only this definition or
>
> declaration, which is probably not what you want iffinder.c: In
>
> function `handle_icmp_error': iffinder.c:1069: error: dereferencing
>
> pointer to incomplete type
>
> ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iffinder.c` line 54 does `#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>` - is this header file present on your system?

Answer (score 2):

In cygwin, the `icmp.h` is empty. I suggest you copy a icmp.h from a open source project, and compile it with your project. Maybe, you have many errors and you have to correct them, but you just need an icmp struct and it will solve your problem.